# Odoo 10 - Javascript - ListView button action not working

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10.

I added a button to the *ListView.buttons*, but I can't link an action to it.

My button:

```
<t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
        <t t-if="widget.fields_view.name == 'site.tree'">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm oe_create_customer_button">
                Create Customer Site
            </button>
        </t>
    </t>
</t>
```

Js code:

```
openerp.broadband = function(instance, local) {

instance.web.ListView.include({
    render_buttons: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        if (this.$buttons) {
            this.$buttons.find('.oe_create_customer_button').on('click', this.proxy('do_new_button'))
        }
    },
    do_new_button: function () {
        this.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            name: 'site_wizard_act_js',
            res_model: 'broadband.wizard',
            view_type: 'form',
            view_mode: 'form',
            view_id: 'site_wizard_act',
            target: 'new',
        })
    }
})
}
```

But Odoo gives me *'TypeError: this.view_order[0] is undefined'* when I click the button.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I added the *'context'* and the *'views'* params in the action.

```
instance.web.ListView.include({
    render_buttons: function() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments)
        if (this.$buttons) {
            this.$buttons.find('.oe_create_customer_button').on('click', this.proxy('do_new_button'))
        }
    },
    do_new_button: function () {
        var context = {
            'id': this.id,
        }
        var action = ({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: 'broadband.wizard',
            view_type: 'form',
            view_mode: 'form',
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            target: 'new',
            context: context
        })
        this.do_action(action)
    }
})
```